# Finding solution of differential equation

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I want to find a root X of equation below

[image: equation]

Given Ls is length of something,f is frequency, X is a function of frequency, tgn is group delay and λ_0 is free space wavelength. If you want to more details, you can reference this document at page 20.

https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/00aps_undefined/RAC-0607-0019_1_5E.pdf

Anyway Ls, tgn and λ_0 these variables can be obtained first.

Then how to find X in Python?
Thanks!

Comment: Please re-state your problem, because it is not clear what you are trying to do. Asking for the "root of a differential equation (DE)" makes no sense. DEs can only have solutions, which are functions of the independent variable.

Comment: What is `f`? You are deriving a constant, so would that be 0?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve a differential equation, you need some initial state information. Then you can either write your own solver, simplest solution would probably be explicit euler, alternatively you can look into this:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint